# run sequence tasks with rxjava and complete the sequence when one task successful

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an array of tasks, every task is also an observable, which will return true or false after subscribe, they need to run in sequence, if one task return true, I would like to don't run remained task.

I have try with Single.concatArray(). but all tasks will run. I have no idea how to stop the sequence.

Comment: Throw an exception instead of returning false.

Comment: Have you considered to use the `takeWhile` operator (http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Flowable.html#takeWhile-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Predicate-)?

Answer (score 0):

just use `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` operators.

```java
Observable.fromArray(false, false, true, false, true)
                .takeUntil(e -> e == true)
                .subscribe();
```